# Android layout inflate exception

Tags: android, android-inflate

I have an app which is working perfect in my smartphone (android 4.2) but when i try to see it on android emulator (android 3.0) it crashes and says:

```
    03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class Space
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.app.appgym.FragmentRegistro2.onCreateView(FragmentRegistro2.java:47)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Space in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.app.appgym-2.apk]
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:542)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-26 19:14:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  ... 20 more
```

This is the layout of fragmentRegistro2:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devadvance.circulartest"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1184dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Nombre" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textonombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/descpnombre"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEstatura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textonombre"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtnombre"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/estatura" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtnombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textonombre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoaltura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEstatura"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEstatura"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txtestatura"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEstatura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="@string/altura"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textoaltura"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:rotation="270" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMas"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textoaltura"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/btnmas" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenos"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnMas"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/btnmenos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPeso"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenos"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/peso" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textopeso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPeso"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPeso"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/textopeso"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textopeso"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textopeso"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/edad" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoedad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEdad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEdad"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txtedad"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/fechaNacimiento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textoedad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pesomanual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is the code:

```
public class FragmentRegistro2  extends Fragment  {
View view;
Button btn,btn2, btn3,btn4,btnMas,btnMenos;
TextView txt,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5;
EditText txtnombre,txtaltura,pesomanual;
SeekBar barraestatura;  CircularSeekBar barrapeso;
boolean isScrollable=false,eventoscroll=false;
DatePicker fechanacimiento;
ScrollView sView;

 public FragmentRegistro2() { 

        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registro2, container, false);
              btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.boton1);
              btn2=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnEstatura); 
              btnMas=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnMas); 
           sView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);

            /*  sView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         sView.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Current Y is : "+sView.getScrollY(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                               }
                                       });
                         if (isScrollable==true){
                         if (sView.getScrollY()>250){
                            // isScrollable=false;
                             sView.smoothScrollTo(0,250);
                             eventoscroll=true;
                         }
                         }
                         /*if(isScrollable==false && eventoscroll==true){
                         if (sView.getScrollY()<250){

                             eventoscroll=false;
                             isScrollable=true;}
                         }*/
                    /*  return !isScrollable;
                    }
                });*/
              btnMas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override         
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        barraestatura.setProgress(barraestatura.getProgress()+1);
                    }

                  });
              btnMenos=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnMenos); 
              btnMenos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override         
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        barraestatura.setProgress(barraestatura.getProgress()-1);
                    }

                  });

              txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textonombre);
              txt2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textoaltura);
              txt3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtEstatura); 
              txtnombre=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtnombre); 
              barraestatura=(SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); 

              txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
              btnMas.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
              btnMenos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
              txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
              barraestatura.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              barraestatura.setMax(230); 
              barraestatura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
               //add here your implementation 
                  } 
                  @Override
                  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
                    //add here your implementation
                  } 
                  @Override
                  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                      boolean fromUser) { 

                  txt3.setText(progress+" cm"); 
                  }
                });
              txtnombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override         
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(txt.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtnombre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cerrarBotones(1);
                    }
                    else{ 
                        txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        txtnombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } 

                }

              });
              btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override        
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(txt2.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnMas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnMenos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barraestatura.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cerrarBotones(2);
                        }
                        else{ 
                            txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnMas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnMenos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            barraestatura.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }

                  });

              txt4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textopeso);
              txt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              pesomanual=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.pesomanual);
              pesomanual.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
              pesomanual.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                  @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }@Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!pesomanual.getText().toString().equals("")){
                int peso= (int) (Float.parseFloat(pesomanual.getText().toString())*10);
                    if(peso>0){
                        barrapeso.setProgress(peso);}}
                }
              });
              barrapeso= (CircularSeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar1); 
              barrapeso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              barrapeso.setMax(1700);
              barrapeso.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CircularSeekBarListener(){
              public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                //  pesomanual.setText(barrapeso.getProgress()*.5f+"");
              }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }});


              btn3=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnPeso);
              btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override        
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(txt4.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        txt4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        barrapeso.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pesomanual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isScrollable=true;
                        cerrarBotones(3);
                        }
                        else{ 
                            txt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            barrapeso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pesomanual.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            sView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
                            isScrollable=false;
                        }

                    }

                  });
              txt5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textoedad);
              txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              fechanacimiento=(DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.fechaNacimiento);
              fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              btn4=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdad);
              btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override        
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(txt5.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        txt5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isScrollable=true;
                        cerrarBotones(4);
                        }
                        else{ 
                            txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            sView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
                            isScrollable=false;
                        }

                    }

                  });

              return view;
        }

        public void cerrarBotones(int boton){
            if(boton==1){
                txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMenos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barraestatura.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barrapeso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pesomanual.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
            }
            if(boton==2){
                txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtnombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barrapeso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pesomanual.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
            }
            if(boton==3){
                txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtnombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMenos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barraestatura.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fechanacimiento.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            if(boton==4){

                txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtnombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMas.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnMenos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barraestatura.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                barrapeso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pesomanual.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Why Am I getting the error only on the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" />
```

Because of `space`. It was introduced in `Android 14` and probably your emulator has an older version (earlier than 14). Since is purpose is  to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts, I think you can change it with

```
<View
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton1"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" />
```

Comment: If it is related, post the new stacktrace otherwise you should ask a new question